# Is it possible to determine by way of T-SQL Query whether a sproc is CLR-based or regular T-SQL-based?

Tags: sql-server-2008, build-process, sqlclr

Hey all.  I'm integrating a CLR/Assembly-based sproc replacement for an existing sproc that lives within our production database, and I want to write an update script that only drops the old T-SQL-based script and doesn't drop the new one if its already there.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query against `sys.objects` where type = 'P' (or `sys.procedures`), only SQL stored procedures are returned and not CLR functions. See [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) or more.

Comment: Hey, Thanks!  I didn't think that it was going to be that easy.  Apparently the CLR-based stored procedure has a [sys.objects].[xtype] of 'PC'.